# Applying Kustomize to a single file

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

I have a pretty standard Kustomize layout of my Kubernetes manifests:

```
deploy/
  base/
    deployment1.yaml
    deployment2.yaml
  overlays/
    dev/
      kustomization.yaml
    uat/
      kustomization.yaml
    prod/
      kustomization.yaml
```

In order to apply Kustomize for one environment, e.g., `dev`, I use

```
kubectl apply -k overlays/dev
```

Now I want to apply Kustomize for one environment, but for *one single file*, e.g., `deployment1.yaml`. I understand I can do so 1) using

```
kubectl kustomize overlays/dev
```

, then 2) manually extracting the output pertaining to `deployment1` into a temporary file `depl.yaml` and then 3) running

```
kubectl apply depl.yaml
```

However, this is tedious. Can I wrap steps 1, 2 and 3 together into a single instruction?

Thanks in advance for you assistance.

Comment: You can use [`kfilt`](https://github.com/ryane/kfilt) to extract just the resource you want from the output of `kustomize` (so `kustomize build ... | kfilt -n deployment1 | kubectl apply -f-`).